# FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed when I am logged in through Settings

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app with facebook integrations und sometimes everything works fine, but now I got some mails that some people cannot login with Facebook.

Now I now what is the problem.

If I am not logged in through the setting in my facebook account everything works fine, but when I logged in through setting I always get in the `sessionStateChanged` funciton the case `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:`

What can I do against it?

Here is my code:

First when I click on login with Facebook I use this function:

```
- (void)facebookLoginFunction {
    if ([self checkInternet]==TRUE) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sessionStateChanged:) name:FBSessionStateChangedNotification object:nil];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        // The person using the app has initiated a login, so call the openSession method
        // and show the login UX if necessary.
       [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
    }
}
```

and the function sessionStateChanged: in the Delegate

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error{

    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: NSLog(@"User session closed");
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:{ NSLog(@"Login failed");
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];}
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

I realy hope that you can help me, cause I dont understand this crazy problem.
thanks

Comment: Quite old post, I guess it's solved meanwhile, but for the history : 
Make sure you both add
    `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{  
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];  
}`
and 
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}`
to your app delegate

Answer (score 3):

Adding both

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url   
{   
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];   
}    

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application   
{   
[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];   
}
```

Worked!

All credits go to Skrew for this answer.